# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, app-engine-flexible

I am getting an error while deploying my project to appengine.
When I run this app locally, its running fine but when I try to deploy this to appengine I am getting the below error. Can someone help here?

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
[INFO] GCLOUD: Application startup error:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Start command: java -showversion -
agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--log_dir=/var/log/app_engine,--
alsologtostderr=true -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:+UseG1GC -
XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -jar app.jar
[INFO] GCLOUD: -XX:InitialHeapSize=514850816 -XX:MaxHeapSize=514850816 -
XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -
XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC 
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.233410    25 jvmti_globals.cc:352] Build time: 
Jun 22 2017 16:09:00
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.239876    25 jvmti_agent.cc:158] Java debuglet 
initialization started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.240190    25 jvmti_agent.cc:192] Java debuglet 
initialization completed
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.356501    25 jvmti_agent.cc:203] Java VM 
started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.369704    25 jvmti_agent.cc:213] 
 JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 13205 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.370100    36 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:99] Agent 
thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.370481    36 jvm_internals.cc:376] Loading 
internals from /opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent_internals.jar
[INFO] GCLOUD: openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-
1~bpo8+1-b11)
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: no main manifest attribute, in app.jar
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.495450    25 jvmti_agent.cc:221] Java VM 
termination
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.781633    36 jni_logger.cc:31] Initializing 
ClassPathLookup, default classpath: true, extra classpath: [], config: null
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.814752    36 jni_logger.cc:31] Total size of 
indexed resources database: 846 bytes
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.825848    36 jvm_internals.cc:132] 
ClassPathLookup constructor time: 48169 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.826359    36 
yaml_data_visibility_config_reader.cc:33] debugger-config.yaml was not 
found.  Using default settings.
[INFO] GCLOUD: E0707 20:55:24.826520    36 jni_bridge.cc:44] Bind not 
allowed after Shutdown
[INFO] GCLOUD: E0707 20:55:24.826850    36 worker.cc:145] HubClient not 
available: debugger thread can't continue.
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.826905    36 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:103] Agent 
thread exited: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.827049    25 worker.cc:116] Debugger threads 
terminated
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0707 20:55:24.827231    25 jvmti_agent.cc:235] 
JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMDeath cleanup time: 331800 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 02:45 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-07T16:55:37-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/524M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-
plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project SXXRXXXXDataFlowTransform: 
Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-
plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
```

I am using mvn appengine:deploy command on sdk terminal to deploy.
My project is a spring boot project.

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml/pom.xml? What instance size is used? The JVM is started with 2gb heap, does your instance have enough memory?